# how to cut a part TextView when a button become visible

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

In the project I'm working on one problem. Can I do this? The name in the center of the top panel attached to the centerInParent. Left of the text i have image. The name can be displayed on the entire width of the zone (when the button is invisible on the right.) If the button is visible, just to the right is cut the name, and the left side remains as it was.

[image][blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa] - when button invisible

[image][blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...][button] - when button visible

Answer (score 1):

//add below attributes in your textivew

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLength="50"
android:lines="1"
android:maxEms="9" //you can choose max length or max ems
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout.

```
image alignparent topleft. 
button aligntparent right. 
text right of image && left of button.
```

Use button Gone and button visible and not invisible.

Comment: Thanks but i have top RelativeLayout. TextView need to be always in CenterHorizontal and Vertical of that top layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the button to be `Visibility.Hidden` when you want it to be invisible and by setting `android:ellipsize="end"` or `.setEllipsize` on the `TextView`.